# Show number of pagination pages even when total under two

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I have implemented pagination to my wp site and pagination works correctly, but when I limit to display lets say 10 posts and I have 9 then it won't show pagination.

Is it possible to show in that case 1?

I read that paginate_links will return void if under 2, but is that somehow changeable?
**(string|array|void) String of page links or array of page links, depending on 'type' argument. Void if total number of pages is less than 2.**

My code currently. It shows pages 1 and 2 when posts > 10, but won't show 1 if posts < 10:

```
    global $wp_query;
        $args_pagination = array(
                        'base' => add_query_arg('paged', '%#%'),
                        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                        'current' => $paged,
                        'prev_next' => false);
        $html .= paginate_links($args_pagination);
```

Edit:
This all function is used as shortcode to use custom pagination in random places of my site (Not random, but not in the place pagination usually is). I used query_posts for that as I honestly don't know that much about wp developement.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array('limit' => 1000, 'type' => 'post'), $atts ));
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

query_posts(array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
        'post_type' => $type, 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' =>'date', 
        'paged' => $paged));

global $wp_query;
$args_pagination = array(
        'base' => add_query_arg('paged', '%#%'),
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'current' => $paged,
                    'prev_next' => false);
    $html .= paginate_links($args_pagination);
```

And I returned html to display it on my pre-designed box.

Comment: What is the actual question?  It seems that you have solved the initial question with your own code that shows 1 page if there are less than 11 posts.

Comment: It won't show 1, it returns void and shows empty space

Comment: "Currently I have it like that and it shows 1 and 2 if I have 11 posts:" what does this mean?

Comment: Edited that sentence a bit

Comment: Got it - that is clear now, thanks. If you test for the void return, you can create your own 1 entry pagination.  Using your code above, `if ( is_null( $html ) ) { //create single page pagination }`.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `$wp_query` global? Have you done the unthinkable and used `query_posts` and now need custom pagination to fix things? Why is this being returned as a string instead of output directly? In order to find a solution we're going to need to know the surrounding context that explains the need for the function and where the values come from for the function call and its arg. Use the edit link under the question tags to add as much information as you can, the key information might even be something you consider obvious or irrelevant, oversharing is good

Comment: @jdm2112 Seems logical yes, don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: @TomJNowell Did update my question with details. And yes, I used query_posts and now I read that it's not recommended practice.

Comment: You should use the `pre_get_posts` posts instead to change what posts a page shows, then the pagination APIs would work as intended with minimal adjustment, and `WP_Query` for secondary post loops

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. `paginate_links()` is hard-coded to stop producing output as soon as it notices that there'll be less than 2 pages. You can see this on lines 4130–4132 of the function's source code here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#source

The only workaround would be to copy the code of `paginate_links()` into your own new function and change the `2` to `1` on what is line 4130 for the existing function.